# Using date as x-axis

Tags: numbers

I wish to create a chart where you can compare how many awards a bunch companies have won over time. After collecting the data I now want to plot it in Numbers. To simplify I have put together some example data. Let's ignore the Award column for now and just focus on the first two columns.
[image]
I wish to create a chart in Numbers that uses the dates from a column as the x-axis and then plots cumulative occurances of "Agency" along the way. Hope the example explains it a bit better. I'm no stats guy.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want the x axis to be labeled? In years, possibly?